# TYPO3 7.6 Extbase / Fluid form: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have got a form, based on Extbase an Fluid in TYPO3 7.6. Every time a validation error in any field occurs, the form gets displayed again showing the validation errors, as desired.
But every time the form gets displayed again and a value has been entered in the date field, the error message `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` appears.

I would like to get rid of this error message.

The controller has a date property in it:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model;

class Person extends BaseDto
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $privatePersonBirthdate
     */
    protected $privatePersonBirthdate;

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $privatePersonBirthdate
     */
    public function setPrivatePersonBirthdate($privatePersonBirthdate)
    {
        $this->privatePersonBirthdate = $privatePersonBirthdate;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPrivatePersonBirthdate()
    {
        return $this->privatePersonBirthdate;
    }

}
```

Template:

```
<f:form.textfield property="privatePersonBirthdate" />
```

Property configuration in controller:

```
$conf->forProperty('privatePersonBirthdate')->setTypeConverterOption('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\TypeConverter\\DateTimeConverter', \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT, 'd.m.Y');
```

I already found some similar reports online, like https://forge.typo3.org/issues/4268.

The workaround using the value attribute would work, but also destroys the value the user entered in the form on validation errors:

```
<f:form.textfield property="privatePersonBirthdate" value="{f:format.date(date: person.privatePersonBirthdate, format: 'd.m.Y')}" />
```

I seems like something is missing. I do not get it. Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The option `features.rewrittenPropertyMapper` has been removed since TYPO3 7, so this has no impact on your problem. 

Where you you initialize the property configuration? Please make sure, that you only use it for the `initializeSaveAction`

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the `features.rewrittenPropertyMapper`.
I initialize the property configuration in both `initializeFormAction` and `initializeSaveAction` action. If I only do it in `initializeSaveAction` the error indeed disappears, but the date I entered before is not shown in the form field on validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue creating a view helper which converts the property of type `DateTime` before trying to render it:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Form\TextfieldViewHelper;

/**
 * This view helper solves the issue described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792891/typo3-7-6-extbase-fluid-form-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-str
 *
 * Class TextfieldForDatesViewHelper
 * @package Educo\Eddaylight\ViewHelpers
 */
class TextfieldForDatesViewHelper extends TextfieldViewHelper
{
    /**
     * Initialize the arguments.
     *
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerTagAttribute(self::DATEFORMAT, 'string', 'Required format for date field');
    }

    /**
     * Converts an arbitrary value to a plain value
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value to convert
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function convertToPlainValue($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $value->format($this->arguments[self::DATEFORMAT]);
        }
        return parent::convertToPlainValue($value);
    }

    const DATEFORMAT = 'dateFormat';
}
```